# How to return an object that was deleted?

Tags: java

I have  a method that is supposed to delete an InventoryItem (i) in an array list (iList) when part of the description of that InventoryItem is entered. The method has to return the item that was deleted, and I'm unsure of how to do this. Here's my code so far.

```
public InventoryItem deleteInventoryItem(String descriptionIn) {

  int index = -1;
  boolean result = false;

  for (InventoryItem i : iList) {
     if (i.getDescription().toLowerCase().startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
        index = (iList.indexOf(i));
        result = true;  
     } 

     if (index >= 0) {
        iList.remove(index);
     } 
  }

  return null;


}
```

Comment: Can't you copy it to a temp object and return that?

Comment: First you get the object at a certain index. Then you remove the object at a certain index. Then you return the object...

Comment: @JeroenVannevel not to mention, `E remove(int index)` returns the object that was removed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***I can't use an iterator. [...] I need to use a for each loop***

Here's one way:

```
public InventoryItem deleteInventoryItem(String descriptionIn) {
    for (InventoryItem item : iList)
        if (item.getDescription()
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
            iList.remove(item);
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that this removes at most one object from the list. If there are multiple matches, only the first match will be removed.

> ***If I simply wanted to find and return an object instead of deleting it, [...]***

Then you simply skip the `iList.remove(item)` row.

But even better would be to split up the methods as follows:

```
public InventoryItem findInventoryItem(String descriptionIn) {
    for (InventoryItem item : iList)
        if (item.getDescription()
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public InventoryItem deleteInventoryItem(String description) {
    InventoryItem item = findInventoryItem(description);
    if (item != null)
        iList.remove(item);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: upvote for taking the time to make it much safer than the OP's original code.

Comment: in OP's code, the function could possibly remove multiple items that are identical.  I'm not sure if it is intentional, but if it is, your code does not work.

Comment: @Justin, no, the OP's code will most likely throw ConcurrentModificationException if *any* element is removed. Updated the answer anyway :-)

Comment: Well you could avoid that ConcurrentModificationException by not using an iterator and looping in a different way.  See my answer.

Comment: @aioobe I need to use a for each loop like you used in the third method, but I need it to actually remove the object. How can I alter that so it works?

Comment: Answer updated. If you need both find and delete, the second approach is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the object before you delete it. Then return that object.

```
public InventoryItem deleteInventoryItem(String descriptionIn) {

  int index = -1;
  boolean result = false;
  for (InventoryItem i : iList) {
     if (i.getDescription().toLowerCase().startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
        index = (iList.indexOf(i));
        result = true;  
     } 

     if (index >= 0) {
        return iList.remove(index);
     } 
  }
  return null;
}
```

**NOTE if this return null means nothing was deleted.**

---

EDIT

If you want to just return the object and not delete it.
Replace `return iList.remove(index);` by `return iList.get(index);`

Comment: Thanks! If I simply wanted to find and return an object instead of deleting it, could I just remove the iList.remove(index)?

Comment: @aioobe yes it will result in `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @kb94, I must comment since you chose to accept this answer: This code will crash on any non-trivial input. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: @aioobe I can't use an iterator. Sorry for not mentioning that before.

Comment: Why can't you use an iterator? (Updated my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `return` keyword in front of your `remove` method. But considering you messed that up and that would cause a ConcurrentModificationException, I changed it a bit.

```
public InventoryItem deleteInventoryItem(String descriptionIn) {
  Iterator<InventoryItem> iterator = iList.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  {
      InventoryItem i = iterator.next();
      if (i.getDescription().toLowerCase().startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
          iterator.remove();
          return i;
      }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: This will most likely throw ConcurrentModificationException since you're modifying a list during a for-each traversal.

Comment: @aioobe oh boy you're right. I copy-pasted his code without thinking, let me fix that

Comment: @aioobe man it's easier if I just rewrite this thing, what the hell. I thought I could just add a `return` and make it work, but I guess this is why people should proof-read what they're doin'.

Answer (score 0):

You are just removing it from the list, not deleting the object from memory. You already have a reference to it, so you can simply return it after removing from the list.

```
for (InventoryItem i : iList) {
    if (i.getDescription().toLowerCase().startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
        iList.remove(i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  I just edited it to avoid ConcurrentModificationException and also moved declaration of index into the for loop.

```
public InventoryItem deleteInventoryItem(String descriptionIn) {
  InventoryItem returnItem = null;
  InventoryItem i = null;
  for (int j = 0; j < iList.size(); j++) {
       boolean result = false;
       i = iList.get(j);
       if (i.getDescription().toLowerCase().startsWith(descriptionIn.toLowerCase())) {
           returnItem = i;
           iList.remove(j);  
           j--;
       } 
   }
   return returnItem;
}
```

Comment: This will most likely throw ConcurrentModificationException since you're modifying a list during a for-each traversal.

Comment: Edited to avoid ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: If you remove `index` and then do `j++` you'll skip over one element unintentionally. `result` is never used. Also, why not do the `iList.remove` inside the if-statement and get rid of the dummy `index` variable.

Comment: not that it matters anymore, but i cleaned it up a bit.